# Error: "include is invalid for non-ParseObjects" (using parse-osx-library-1.7.5)

Tags: parse-platform, local-datastore

I have a Meal object that stores pointers to n created objects "FoodInfo" using the key "MealItems".

When I query for the meal I take advantage of the [query includeKey:@"MealItems"] to fetch the items pointed to while fetching the "Meal".

This works swimmingly if the objects are created while online (ie. all are stored in the cloud db).

However, since I cannot assume access to the cloud at all time for this app I am now trying to enable the local datastore so I've changed my queries to use:
    [query fromLocalDatastore];

and I've changed all of my objects' save methods to pinInBackgroundWithBlock followed by (assuming success of local save) saveInBackgroundWithBlock followed by (assuming failure) saveEventually.

To test this, I:

- turned off wifi
- ran the code to create a meal and then add newly created foods to it.  This works with no error codes.
- ran a report that then queries for the meal just created. This fails with the following:

```
Error: Error Domain=Parse Code=121 
"include is invalid for non-ParseObjects" UserInfo=0x60800007f400 {
    error=include is invalid for non-ParseObjects, 
    NSLocalizedDescription=include is invalid for non-ParseObjects, 
    code=121
} {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "include is invalid for non-ParseObjects";
    code = 121;
    error = "include is invalid for non-ParseObjects";
}
```

Is this scenario not supported?

When I re-enable wifi, the meal is successfully added to the online db, but the query failure still happens when I run the query with the includeKey locally.

Am I missing something here? I'm quite surprised to see this failing. It seems like a really basic feature that should work whether local or cloud based.

Comment: Show the code you're using for the test

Comment: The fundamental question shouldn't require showing code. It is clearly possible to create an object A that contains an array of pointers to other objects and pin them all to the local datastore while offline. Does parse support a local datastore query that retrieves A and the objects pointed to in the array via includekey prior to any of the objects being saved over the network?

Comment: Wondering if this was addressed on any of the newer versions or if you would mind to share your workaround if any @Gerald. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parse objects are not created until you save them. Try using `saveEventually` first before using `pinInBackgroundWithBlock`.

Comment: Calling saveEventually prior to pinning an object (in the absence of a network connection) doesn't change anything. This results in exactly the same error I reported above.  I'm guessing the includekey fails because the PFObject has not been assigned an id and said assignment seems not to occur prior to the object being saved via a network connection.  If so, this renders the use of includekey to retrieve 1:n relations unusable for the offline scenario in which objects are created, pinned (and saved eventually), then referenced via a query using includekey.